# To which country to pay the taxes if providing services online internationally?

Tags: taxes, international

If I provide services online to the international clients, do I have to pay the taxes only to the country of which I am a tax resident or I may have some tax obligations in other countries too?

I would like to hope that there is a uniform answer for all kinds of services, but if not, I am interested in the following examples:

1. online tutoring
2. online consultancy
3. programming and data analysis

Comment: Welcome new user.  You would, absolutely, need to state the country pair you are interested in.  It is totally different for every country, and contra-country.

Answer (score 1):

Just scratching the surface but if your client is a non-taxable customer located in the EU (i.e. a private individual, not a business), VAT on digital service must be charged at the [rate of the country where they reside](https://europa.eu/youreurope/business/taxation/vat/vat-digital-services-moss-scheme/index_en.htm). This applies even if you are yourself located outside the EU (and being located outside the EU would mean that you're not covered by the special rules for low annual turnovers).

So the answer is yes, you may have some tax obligations in other countries than your own and it does in fact depend on the nature of the services but also on the exact pair of countries. You won't find a uniform answer simplifying all this and will need to consider if taking up new clients in an unfamiliar country is worth the trouble.